# Can I pass my player name on the command line when launching the game?

Tags: counter-strike

Is it possible to pass the `name` parameter on the command line when launching Counter-Strike?

I have tried this and it does not work:

```
-nojoy -nomaster -nointro -game cstrike -appid 10 -gl -steam +nameExample
```

Answer (score 1):

The command in console is no longer name, but "setinfo name" , so what you want to add is then:

```
+setinfo name "Name goes here"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a short list of things you can pass on the command line, and not every config file option is supported.  There's a full list of what command line parameters exist on [this page.](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Command-line_parameters_2)  (Note that the original CounterStrike is a "Gold Source" game.)

You can, however, do this by having the correct command in a config file.  The list of config file commands is far longer, and is on [this page.](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Console_commands_list)  I covered how to create config files in this question:

[How do I use a script without having to type it in the console row by row?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73078/how-do-i-use-a-script-without-having-to-type-it-in-the-console-row-by-row)

You won't need to read the part about binding keys to "exec" other configs, since you're not doing that.  Also, since the asker of that question was playing TF2, you'll have to adapt the "cfg" directory path to where your CounterStrike install is.

If you want to run this config every time the game starts, pass `+exec whatever.cfg` on the command line, which will execute a custom config file named "whatever.cfg".

Also, typically the game will automatically execute `autoexec.cfg` if there is one present in the cfg\ directory of your CounterStrike install, which would save you from having to specify any additional command line parameters.